# T-SQL error: Adding a value to a 'smalldatetime' column caused overflow. SQL server bug?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

When I try to execute the following code, I get error "Adding a value to a 'smalldatetime' column caused overflow":

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, BegDate SMALLDATETIME, EndDate SMALLDATETIME)

INSERT INTO @t
SELECT NEWID(), '19000101', '20151124'

-- This is to show you that nothing is really selected
SELECT 'You will never see it'
FROM @t r1
INNER JOIN @t r2 ON r2.ID = r1.ID
WHERE   1=1
    AND r1.BegDate > r2.BegDate    
    AND r1.EndDate <= r2.EndDate

SELECT r1.ID, r2.BegDate, DATEADD(DAY, -1, r1.BegDate) AS EndDate
FROM @t r1
INNER JOIN @t r2 ON r2.ID = r1.ID
WHERE   1=1
    AND r1.BegDate > r2.BegDate  -- This guarantees that r1.BegDate is not minimal value
    AND r1.EndDate <= r2.EndDate
```

As you can see, result of DATEADD() cannot be less than minimal value. Moreover, DATEADD() must not be called, because SELECT must return nothing.
Is it an SQL server bug?

Comment: Why did you select `smalldatetime`? It has a limited range (and 1899-12-31 is out of range) and in your case, you seem to be looking for `date`

Comment: See [SQL Server should not raise illogical errors](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/537419/sql-server-should-not-raise-illogical-errors) and feel free to vote on it, but also feel free to be depressed by how old it is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [smalldatetime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182418.aspx) value has the following date range:

> 1900-01-01 through 2079-06-06
>
> January 1, 1900, through June 6, 2079

You are getting the error because your calculation is leading to date out of this boundaries:

```
DECLARE  @BegDate SMALLDATETIME = '19000101'
SELECT @BegDate
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -1, @BegDate)
```

The questions is why the `SELECT` stuff is executed before the `FROM`, `JOIN` and `WHERE` stuff, as this is not the [Logical Processing Order of the SELECT statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx).

If you change the `19000101` value to `19000102`, just to get the execution plan the SQL engine is building, you should see this:

[image]

The `Compute Scalar` is actually the `DATEADD` function execution:

[image]

So, the `DATEADD` function is executed and throws an error. This is caused because:

> Note that the actual physical execution of the statement is determined
>   by the query processor and the order may vary from this list.

---

```
SELECT r1.ID, r2.BegDate, IIF(r1.BegDate = '19000101', NULL, DATEADD(DAY, -1, r1.BegDate)) AS EndDate
FROM @t r1
INNER JOIN @t r2 ON r2.ID = r1.ID
WHERE   1=1
    AND r1.BegDate > r2.BegDate  -- This guarantees that r1.BegDate is not minimal value
    AND r1.EndDate <= r2.EndDate
```

You can use the `OPTION(FORCE ORDER)` to change the execution plan and make your query work:

```
SELECT r1.ID, r2.BegDate, DATEADD(DAY, -1, r1.BegDate) AS EndDate
FROM @t r1 
INNER JOIN @t r2 ON r2.ID = r1.ID
WHERE   1=1
    AND r1.BegDate > r2.BegDate  -- This guarantees that r1.BegDate is not minimal value
    AND r1.EndDate <= r2.EndDate
OPTION  (FORCE ORDER)
```

[image]

Comment: Guys, I know range of SMALLDATETIME, but my WHERE clause has predicates that make impossible execution of DATEADD(DAY,-1,'19000101'). But seems that SQL Server thinks it's very smart and try to prevent error that I have already prevented. And I cannot find any workaround for this odd behavior.

Comment: your workaround is not equivalent to my code: I need DATEADD(DAY, -1, r1.BegDate), but you propose DATEADD(DAY, -1, r2.BegDate) instead.

Comment: @FameT. Then just use `IIF` to skip the operation in this case.

Comment: Why use `smalldate` at all? `date` is the appropriate type if no time portion is needed

Comment: PS the problem isn't that SQL Server "thinks it's very smart" but the assumption that somehow the query expressions dictate the data processing order. This is incorrect. The job of the database is to perform queries as fast as possible. This means that calculations will occur where they will incur the least cost.

Comment: @FameT. You can use `OPTION(FORCE ORDER)` to solve this.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - there is a logical processing order that SQL database products *ought* to either follow or, if they choose not to, ought to produce the same behaviour "as if" they had followed the logical processing order. The problem is, SQL Server sometimes violates this "as if" requirement.

Answer (score 1):

I received an answer here:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/1a60b3a1-0e18-41aa-b40a-bc64558f6ce2/tsql-error-adding-a-value-to-a-smalldatetime-column-caused-overflow-sql-server-bug?forum=transactsql&prof=required

In this situation I can use OPTION(FORCE ORDER):

```
SELECT r1.ID, r2.BegDate, DATEADD(DAY, -1, r1.BegDate) AS EndDate
FROM @t r1
INNER JOIN @t r2 ON r2.ID = r1.ID
WHERE   1=1
    AND r1.BegDate > r2.BegDate  -- This guarantees that r1.BegDate is not minimal value
    AND r1.EndDate <= r2.EndDate
OPTION(FORCE ORDER)
```